# Header and Footer at ListView Adapter

Tags: android, header, android-listview

```
try {           
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
    }
    is.close();
    resultString = sb.toString();
    String[] ArrayStr = Func.split(resultString, "|*|");
    String[] arr;

    lv = new ListView(context);
    lv.setAdapter(null);        
    // populate
    ArrayList<Device> m_Devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
    Device device;
    for(int i = 0; i < ArrayStr.length; i++){
        arr = Func.split(ArrayStr[i], "|**|");
        device = new Device(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
        m_Devices.add(device);
    }
    // +header n footer (must above custom adapter)

    View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    lv.addHeaderView(v1);


    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
    lv.addFooterView(v);



    // custom adapter
    CustomAdapter lvAdapter =  new CustomAdapter(context, m_Devices);
    lv.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(Menu1.this);
    adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
    adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    adb.show();
    }

    });
```

How to make the header and footer become static?
the header n footer become scrollable too, like the list view..
i had google n there is someone sugest 4 placing the header and footer outside the listview, but i don't know place to where ?  i'm already try place it to my custom adapter n there's no good... so plz anybody can tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have a look at [footerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) and [headerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: For sticky Header and Footer, have a look this useful [blog](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/)

Comment: @adil i know placing the header and footer when using xml. but when i used custom adapter, i can't use the xml but must at java file.. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think placing them outside of the ListView means that you should use custom view elements e.g. TextViews which you place above and below the ListView. These elements have nothing to do with the ListView anymore. So you cannot access them with `lv.addHeaderView(v1);` or `lv.addFooterView(v);` anymore. Instead you have to treat them like normal TextView elements. Of course you can also use custom Views instead of TextViews.

**Update**

The layout for you activity should look something like that. The first TextView is the header, followed by the ListView and below this we got another TextView as a footer. Header and footer don't need to TextViews they can be any kind of View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/header_txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer Text"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/footer_txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So you will bind the adapter to the ListView as you already did. To set the text for the header and footer you use the following lines.

```
TextView header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_text);
header.setText("This is my header text");
TextView footer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.footer_text);
footer.setText("This is my footer text");
```

Comment: @flo can u give me example the format? bcoz i already trying so many possiblelity, but no one fixed my problem... thx 4 ur assistent :)

Comment: @Flo where must i put that code? i do create another LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(context); LL.addView(header); LL.addView(lv); LL.addView(Footer); setContainer(LL); i think the logic is rigth but still error....  this listview really really something

Comment: Sorry, there were some problems with the formatting of my answer, so layout xml I posted wasn't shown. Mh what error do you get? Can you add your current code to your initial question and also add the error form the cat log?

Comment: @Flo oh i see now, u're using XML, i have 2 options.. at this one i cannot using static header bcoz i dont use the XML for setcontentview, but it's can be clicked... in another option i'm using XML like yours, it's nice, but cannot be clicked... it's frustating me... if u in my condition, witch one do u use?

Comment: What do you mean with cannot be clicked? You can bind an OnClickListener to the header and footer view in you code although you're using xml layouts. But of course you can also build up the layout by code. You simply should not use the addHeaderView() and addFooterView() methods as they will always scroll with the list.

Comment: @Flo Thx flo, i had change my whole code.... so the layout nice n can be click :)